# Create cookie before authentication in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, cookies

I have a scenario in which I need to create a cookie before user is authenticated by my MVC application. Now, here, login is done using external application. (which lies on different server). For this, I did below code in my local environment. I am overriding built-in Authorize attribute and use my custom attribute.

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    HttpCookie _testCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
    _redirectCookie.Value = "someValue";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(_testCookie);
    base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);   
}
```

Above code works if I have local url in  tag in my web.config. Can somebody please tell me if the same will work with external login url or not?

Thanks in advance,
Suhani.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. solved it.. I just had to use the same domain name while creating this cookie so that the consuming site can see the cookie created by the original site. Deployed the same code (adding domain name while creating a cookie) and it worked.

thank you anyways!